# Single page template not working for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, wordpress-theming, hierarchy, custom-post-type

I have 3 different type of custom post types and using **Redux framework**. All are working but facing two problem. If i unset the framework, it works fine.

1. `the_permalink()` is missing post_type in URL like following:
   should be `http://sitename/product/abc` but getting `http://sitename/abc`.
   and it takes me to 404 page.(*In product edit screen i got correct slug, but not with `the_permalink()`*)
2. When i correct the url manually (`http://sitename/product/abc`), it takes me to homepage. But it should be in single-product.php or single.php page.

I used following code to make Custom post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'tormuz_product_cpt' );
function tormuz_product_cpt() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Products', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Product', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Product' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Product' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Product' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Products' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Product' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Products' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No products found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No products found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Products'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our products and product specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 45,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'has_archive'   => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'product', $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

I am running `WordPress 3.9` and `Redux 3.2.0` **without** `dev_mode` enabled.

My permalink structure: `/%postname%/`

Please let me know, if it can be solved.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved following way:
**Disabled** the framework and **enabled** it again. It works :)

Comment: Just needed to flush your URL cache it seems? heh.